# Spark Int and Integer, udf

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I just began to learn Spark. I tried to define a UDF for my data frame. It is a very simple function like this: column is Long type in dataframe.

```
def category: (Int => Int) ={ a=>

if(a<7){
    return a
}
else{
    if(a>=7 && a<14){
        return 8
    }
    else{
        if(a>=14 && a<28){
            return 9
        }
        else{
            return 10


           }
        }
    }

}

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
val myudf = udf(category)

val df_1 = df.withColumn("ncol", myudf($col))
```

It always reports errors:

```
:78: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: Int => Int
               return a
                      ^
:82: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(8)
 required: Int => Int
                   return 8
                          ^
:86: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(9)
 required: Int => Int
                       return 9
                              ^
:89: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(10)
 required: Int => Int
                       return 10
                              ^
```

Comment: you have defined return type as `(Int => Int)` and you are returning just Integer value. The error log is clear i guess. you had to return integer only i guess.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan the type declaration is fine, problem is with the `return` statements inside the function

Comment: @puhlen yes i understand that. the OP needs to return a function not an Integer. By the way I have answered stating one of the correct ways to define udf function using the OP's logic.

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of your return statements.  `return` is unnecessary in most scala code, as the last expression is returned automatically (this works for if statements as well, the whole if is a statement that returns a value).  It's not recommended to use `return` when you don't have to as it can cause some unexpected behaviour like you are experiencing here.

lets simplify your code

```
def category: (Int => Int) ={ a=>
  return a
}
```

This will fail to compile.  `category` is a method that takes no arguments and returns a function `Int => Int`. So far so good.  But now `return a` causes the method to return the value of `a`, which is an `Int`.  This breaks because we wanted and `Int => Int` and we return an `Int`.  To fix this, just remove the return.

```
def category: (Int => Int) = { a=>
  a
}
```

Now the code works, because the last (and only) expression in our method is the function `a => a` which is an `Int => Int` just like we wanted.  The function here is kinda boring, it just returns the input without changes.

Lets try it with your function

```
def category: (Int => Int) ={ a=>
    if(a<7){
        a
    }
    else{
        if(a>=7 && a<14){
            8
        }
        else{
            if(a>=14 && a<28){
                9
            }
            else{
                10
               }
            }
        }
}
```

Now it works because instead of trying to return an `Int` from within the function, we return the entire function which is what we want.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the column type is `Long`, your `category` method should take `Long` parameter rather than `Int`.  Here's how I would define the function:

```
def category: (Long => Long) = { a =>
  if (a < 7) a else
    if (a < 14) 8 else
      if (a < 28) 9 else
        10
}

val myudf = udf(category)
```

Or, you could just create the `UDF` in one code block:

```
val myudf = udf(
  (a: Long) =>
    if (a < 7) a else
      if (a >= 7 && a < 14) 8 else
        if (a >= 14 && a < 28) 9 else
          10
)
```

Comment: This does not address the problem causing the error op has, namely trying to use `return` in a function.

Comment: @puhlen, you're right that the using of `return` is indeed the main issue.  Thanks for pointing it out.  There is also an argument type problem that would render the UDF inapplicable, though it doesn't cause the reported issue.